# How does one combine Authorization Code Flow with ROPC flow in ASP.NET Core in Azure AD?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core server application (.net 6.x) that supports the textbook example shown in
[Sign in users and call Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph)

It works as desired.  I can, from different clients use the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE, have a user log in, and then call a web API that in turn makes use of the Microsoft Graph OBO of that user.

This works great for interactive applications where a UI can be presented.

I have an additional requirement to also support a functionally equivalent flow, simultaneously, that can be executed from a daemon (Windows Service).

The flow that seems best suited is the ROPC flow.  I understand that it is not recommended, but is supported.  Presumably, the user+password will be stored securely on the machine running the service. The client credentials flow does not suit my requirements well, because the resources to be accessed are user-dependent, and the user is not fixed.  Multiple services may be running on different nodes against the same server with different users.

Is this even possible, and if so what additions or changes are needed on the ASP.NET Core server?  What might the client code resemble (.NET Framework 4.8)?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

is how authentication is configured.

It occurs to me that just using the ROPC flow *should* just work without changes to the server code.  Instead of a client app that uses the OAuth2 Authorization Code flow with PKCE, I just use the ROPC flow.

If you can see any gotchas (besides the user+password being not recommended), please let me know as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-console-up-v2/blob/main/up-console/PublicAppUsingUsernamePassword.cs#L62) and document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/desktop-mobile/username-password-authentication).

and my code test:

```
IPublicClientApplication App = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.
    Create("client_id")
    .WithTenantId("tenant_id")
    .Build();
AuthenticationResult res = await App.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(
    new string[] { "User.Read" }, 
    "user_account", 
    "password").ExecuteAsync();
```

Pls make sure the **azure ad app is a public app** so that we don't require client secret to generate access token and we could use `PublicClientApplicationBuilder` here, or we have to use `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` for `withClientSecret()` but this is not for ROPC flow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I trust that there is no change needed for the Auth Code flow (which worked just fine).

Comment: yes I also think so : ) and thank you for your response